# Getting checkbox options for a new entry, without having an entry

Tags: templating, entry, fieldtypes, checkboxes

How would I get a list of all the checkbox options associated with a specific field, without having an entry to loop over? I'm using the same form for creating new entries and editing existing ones. Been using *{{ entry.fieldValue | default( ) }}* for almost everything else.

```
{% if entry is defined and entry.id is not empty %}
    {% for option in entry.myFieldOptions.options %}
        <div class="checkbox">
            {% set checked = false %}

            {% if option.selected %}
                {% set checked = true %}
            {% endif %}

            {% if not checked %}
                <input type="hidden" name="fields[myFieldOptions][]" value="">
            {% endif %}

            <input type="checkbox" value="{{ option.value }}" name="fields[myFieldOptions][]" {% if option.selected %} checked="checked"{% endif %}>{{ option.label }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    //hardcoded values
    //is there a way to reference available checkbox options directly?
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pull the field directly using [`craft.fields`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.fields):

```
{% set myFieldOptions = craft.fields.getFieldbyHandle('myFieldOptions') %}
```

The options will be available under the field's `settings.options` property. Each option will have attributes for `value` and `label`:

```
{% for option in myFieldOptions.settings.options %}
    {{ option.label }} {{ option.value }}
{% endfor %}
```